# How to create the expected button in HTML?

Tags: html, css, button, hover

The first image was captured in Python online course. The second image was captured in my own website. I want to mimic this website for practicing html/css skill. What I want to know is how to create the expected button. Thank you for your reply.

[image: First image]

```
/*Here is my CSS code, which is unfinished.*/
.Matter a:hover{
    background-color: rgb(230,230,230);
}





<!-- Here is my HTML code -->
<div class='Matter'>
    <h1>Welcome to the Capstone</h1>
        <p><a href='#'><b>Video:</b> Introduction: Welcome to the Class</a></p>
        <p><a href='#'><b>Reading:</b> Capstone Overview</a></p>
        <p><a href='#'><b>Reading:</b> Help Us Learn More About You!</a></p>
</div>
```

[image: second image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's handle your problem step by step:

1. Styling the link: We are going to add some [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding), [text decoration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration) and [color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color). We are also using [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) `inline-block` for our link take full width.

```css
.Matter a {
  padding: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

2. Adding hover style:

```css
.Matter a:hover{
    background-color: rgb(230,230,230);
}
```

3. Adding `checkmark`: We need to use [CSS Pseudo element `::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) to add the check mark in front of the link. To add the green circle around the check mark we are using some [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin), padding, [border radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius), background, color and [font size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size). We are also using [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to adjust the check mark circle position.

```css
.Matter a::before {
  content: '';
  margin-right: 8px;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
}
```

Here's the complete solution. You can play with it as you wish.

```css
.Matter a {
  padding: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.Matter a:hover{
    background-color: rgb(230,230,230);
}

.Matter a::before {
  content: '';
  margin-right: 8px;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
}
```

```html
<div class='Matter'>
    <h1>Welcome to the Capstone</h1>
        <p><a href='#'><b>Video:</b> Introduction: Welcome to the Class</a></p>
        <p><a href='#'><b>Reading:</b> Capstone Overview</a></p>
        <p><a href='#'><b>Reading:</b> Help Us Learn More About You!</a></p>
</div>
```